# Convert comma separated string to integer in R

Tags: r

I have a line in following format

IP1: IP2: 0.1,0.5,0.9

I split this line using following command:

`myVector <- (strsplit(oneLine, ":"))`
,where oneline is string "IP1: IP2: 0.1,0.5,0.9"

I want to access the third column and convert it into data frame. 
I access the third column as below:
listofPValues <- myVector[[1]][[3]]

```
listofPValues <- myVector[[1]][[3]]
```

I am trying to convert the comma separated values in listofPValues to dataframe as below:

```
data.frame(as.numeric(listofPValues,',')))
```

It gives me following error

```
In data.frame(as.numeric(listofPValues, ",")) :
 NAs introduced by coercion
```

The function that I want to use accepts only data frames.
I guess the problem is I need to break the string "0.1,0.5,0.9" before I convert it to numeric.
Please let me know if you have any suggestion.

Thanks
tictactoe

Comment: Try `scan` or `strsplit` again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here'a an approach using `scan`:

```
oneLine <- "IP1: IP2: 0.1,0.5,0.9"
myVector <- strsplit(oneLine, ":")
listofPValues <- myVector[[1]][[3]]
listofPValues
# [1] " 0.1,0.5,0.9"
scan(text = listofPValues, sep = ",")
# Read 3 items
# [1] 0.1 0.5 0.9
```

And one using `strsplit`:

```
as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(listofPValues, ",")))
# [1] 0.1 0.5 0.9
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `gregexpr` and `regmatches`to extract the numbers:

```
as.numeric(unlist(regmatches(oneLine, gregexpr("-?\\d+\\.\\d+", oneLine))))
# [1] 0.1 0.5 0.9
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
as.numeric( str_extract_all(oneLine, "\\b[0-9.]+\\b")[[1]])
[1] 0.1 0.5 0.9
```

#### data

```
oneLine <- "IP1: IP2: 0.1,0.5,0.9"
```