# Read comma separated string to numeric and create dataframe

Tags: r

I have been trying to apply a method to set of values. I want something on following lines:

```
library(MADAM)

fisher.method(data.frame(0.0001879,2.2e-16))

##          S num.p p.value p.adj
## 1 89.26501     2       0     0
```

However, the values to use are in a file that I read one line at a time. If I use strsplit as suggested at [Convert comma separated string to integer in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26342620/convert-comma-separated-string-to-integer-in-r) I get:

```
oneLine <- "0.0001879, 2.2e-16"

fisher.method(data.frame(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(oneLine, ",")))))

##          S num.p      p.value        p.adj
## 1 17.15920     1 1.879000e-04 1.879000e-04
## 2 72.10581     1 2.220446e-16 4.440892e-16
```

How can I get as expected? That is, create dataframe from these individual values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 library(MADAM)
 lapply(strsplit(oneLine, ","),
              function(x) fisher.method(as.data.frame.list(as.numeric(x))))
  #[[1]]
  #         S num.p p.value p.adj
  #1 89.26501     2       0     0
```

If you have a `vector`

```
  Lines <- c("0.0001879, 2.2e-16", "0.001435, 1.2e-14", "0.00014353, 2.5e-13")
  do.call(rbind,lapply(strsplit(Lines, ","), 
        function(x) fisher.method(as.data.frame.list(as.numeric(x)))))
  #         S num.p      p.value        p.adj
 # 1 89.26501     2 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00
 #11 77.20092     2 6.661338e-16 6.661338e-16
 #12 75.73256     2 1.443290e-15 1.443290e-15
```

If you are reading from a file, for example if the contents of `file1.csv` is

```
 0.0001879, 2.2e-16
 0.001435, 1.2e-14
 0.00014353, 2.5e-13
```

Then, you can use `read.csv` to read the file and apply `fisher.method` directly on the two column `data.frame`

```
 dat <- read.csv("file1.csv", header=FALSE)
 fisher.method(dat)
  #          S num.p      p.value        p.adj
  #1 89.26501     2 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00
  #2 77.20092     2 6.661338e-16 9.992007e-16
  #3 75.73256     2 1.443290e-15 1.443290e-15
```